# How to limit numpy float computation precision

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

I am using numpy to calculate camera images, which would be represented by unsigned integer grayvalues.
I would like to limit the floating point accuracy, in order to speed up the computation.
So as an example, say I'm calculating the image formed by the intensity distribution of a gaussian beam:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nx = 1000
ny = 1000
px = 5e-3

x = np.linspace(0, nx * px)
y = np.linspace(0, ny * px)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

xc = x[-1] / 2
yc = y[-1] / 2
sigma = 1

gauss_profile = np.exp(-(np.square(X - xc) + np.square(Y - yc)) / sigma**2)
print(gauss_profile.dtype)

bitdepth = 12
gauss_profile *= 2**bitdepth - 1
camera_image = gauss_profile.astype(np.uint16)

#%% plot image
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
grey_cmap = plt.get_cmap('gray')
im = ax.imshow(camera_image,
               cmap=grey_cmap,
               extent=(0, nx * px,
                       0, ny * px))
plt.xlabel('x (mm)')
plt.ylabel('y (mm)')
plt.colorbar(im)
```

Is there any way to have gauss_profile not be calculated with float64 precision, but rather a minimum resolution which is enough to get the desired gray value?
So far, I tried initializing the array before and passing it to the `out` keyword in the np.exp call, but this resulted in a TypeError or ValueError depending on the dtype. Is there any other way to accelerate this computation?

Comment: [`cv2.GaussianBlur()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1).

Comment: @QuangHoang Please elaborate, don't just link a function from another library...

Comment: @AKX that's why it's a comment, I can't guarantee that it would work for OP's purpose.

Comment: You can try to make your arrays `float32`, but I don't think you'll get much mileage out of that.

Comment: My laptop is able to compute 2000 of those `camera_image`s in 0.22 seconds. Are you running this on some very constrained device, or do the parameters change a lot..?

Comment: Why not precompute the blur for an array big enough for the value to go to zero, and subset your computations to the relevant portions of the image?

Comment: @AKX. Premature optimization...

Comment: @MadPhysicist It's not really premature optimization, I just simplified my use case without getting into any physics. I might very well have to evaluate a method up to 100.000 times at different positions on the same image. Also the gaussian bell curve is just the first approximation for more complex point spread functions corresponding to a micro lens array and is basically representing any numpy.ufunc with a similar shape, which might become much more computation intensive (airy function etc). Computing on relevant slices of the array is a good tip. Thanks, but I'm already doing that.

Comment: @QuangHoang I'm not trying to apply a gaussian blur to the image. I'm simulating light spots

Comment: @Richard In this case, simplifying your use case for SO was probably not the right call, then :-) So what exactly would you do with a `camera_image`? Would you be able to just slap an `lru_cache` decorator on the function that computes it?

Comment: @AKX If I understand lru_cache correctly, it only saves results for parameters and you benefit when you use the same values often. Due to the parameters being float values describing positions without doubles, I don't think this will help. I will draw many white spots onto the camera image on defined positions with sub-pixel accuracy.

Comment: @Richard It would have been useful to know that in your original question, you know. ;-) Either way, what if you consider this "aperture image" a "brush" (that you can easily cache with just a handful of arguments) that you can then paint onto your camera image with a simple `+=` operation?

Comment: @AKX that sounds like it would work. There is only one parameter (gaussian width sigma) staying constant though, x, xc, y, yc change for every call. Specifying my usecase better would have been important for general tips, but I was specifically wondering about the possibility to speed it up by using better suited dtypes.

Comment: Based on your example, I think the signature for the aperture image would be `def compute_camera_image(nx, ny, px, sigma, bitdepth)`, which should be cacheable...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try setting your ndarrays `x` and `y` with dtype [np.half](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.double) or [np.single](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html#numpy.double). This will limit the float precision. But I don't know if the computation is still happening though.

> np.half: Half-precision floating-point number type. (float16)

> np.single: Single-precision floating-point number type, compatible with C float.(float32)

```
x = np.linspace(0, nx * px, dtype=np.half)
y = np.linspace(0, ny * px, dtype=np.half)

...
```